# How private is Strike by Zap?

Tags: lightning-network, privacy, zap

I am asking myself how much information can Strike theoretically collect on its users? Does Lightning have any benefits in this case?
https://medium.com/@JimmyMow/announcing-strike-by-zap-4f578c7c8984